# Looping and skipping in bash

Tags: bash

when I was solving a Hackerrank Linux shell problem, I stuck.

My task is to use *for* loops to display only *odd* natural numbers from 1 to 99.

I tried the followong code but I got wrong. Who can explain this?

My code:

```
for i in {1..100};
do
  if [[$((i % 2)) !=  0 ]] ;then
    echo "$i"
  fi
done
```

[problem link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bash-tutorials---looping-and-skipping/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&isFullScreen=false)

only odd numbers from 1 to 99

Comment: `for i in {1..100..2}`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add details in which way it is wrong. Show the error or unexpected output. Put your code in a single code block instead of using paragraphs with inline code. You can copy&paste the whole code and insert separate lines containing 3 backticks each before and after the code. You can use https://www.shellcheck.net to find errors in a shell script. This will report a missing space after `[[`.

Comment: Paste your code into [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and fix the errors ndicated there.

Comment: FYI, `[[$((i % 2)) !=  0 ]]` does not make a lot of sense to write. `[[ ]]` is for string tests, `(( ))` for numerical tests. So you can do `(( (i % 2) != 0 ))`

Answer (score 1):

this line:  `if [[$((i % 2)) !=  0 ]] ;then` should have a space after `[[`:
`if [[ $((i % 2)) !=  0 ]] ;then`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest starting at 1 and then increasing by 2 at a time.

```
for ((i=1;i<=100;i=i+2)); do echo "$i"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

What you were trying to do -

```
for i in {1..100}; do ((i%2))&&echo $i; done
```

Cyrus' is better.

```
for i in {1..100..2}; do echo $i; done
```

And shellcheck.net would have told you the problem immediately.

```
Line 3:
  if [[$((i % 2)) !=  0 ]] ;then
     ^-- SC1035 (error): You need a space after the [[ and before the ]].
```

Bookmark it. Use it regularly.

Comment: Cyrus forgot the "do"

Comment: Oops... Obviously not Cyrus' fault, as he only showed the step syntax, and it was me who provided the broken code for the rest of the loop. Thanks for the callout!